# Prevent rspec from outputting server and database logs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

When I run rspec, I get this included in the console:

```
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM     "schema_migrations"
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-01-28 11:44:06 -0600
Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
Rendered home/index.html.haml within layouts/application (28.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 54ms (Views: 52.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
```

Here is my spec_helper.rb:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = if example.metadata[:js]
      :truncation
    else
      :transaction
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

I am also using rbenv, sqlite and Ubuntu if that helps.  I am using rails 4.1.0beta1 and I run rspec using the spring command `bin/rspec`.

Comment: How are you running rspec?

Comment: @Jon I just updated the post with more information.

Comment: Thanks ... but what command and options are you using when you run rspec?

Comment: I just use `bin/rspec`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm using rbenv as well, and to silence the logs you can execute the following in console (might be helpful to setup a shortcut):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = Logger::INFO
ActionController::Base.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
Rails.logger.level = Logger::ERROR
```

Comment: I added this to my rails_helper file, and it worked great.  Thanks.

Comment: Worked here too. Thanks!